# blender not assigning the right colour to selected faces

Tags: materials

I selected the first material to be white.  I understand this is the base material.  Then I selected 4 faces as per the screenshot[image: shows five selected faces] Then I created a new colour yellow and tried to assign this to the faces but it coloured the whole thing in yellow. next screenshot[image: showing yellow everywhere] I have read some of the posts about this but cant find a solution.  Is there a bug in the system?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new material slot and assign the faces to that slot. What you've done is simply change the material for the base colour slot.
[image]